# Deriving the value of $\pi$ from a dart board

Tags: probability, geometry, pi

I saw this on a website and it was pretty interesting:

[image]

The circle inscribed in the square has a radius of $1$ and the square has a side length of $2$. This means that the area of the circle is:

$$\pi \times r^{2} = \pi \times (1^2) = \pi$$

Moreover, the area of the square is:

$$(2^2) = 4$$

Then, we can randomly select points within the square and get a good approximation of pi by doing this thousands to millions of times, maybe by a computer sequence. Once we've repeated this process enough, we can plug our values into this equation:

$$ \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\text{Number of points within the circle}}{\text{Total number of points}}$$

Is this a viable approach to approximate the value of $\pi$?

Comment: Lookup bufons needle; no it is not

Comment: Not a particularly useful one, no. You'd certainly need a large sample to get even close to $\pi$, although I'd have to brush up on my stats to know what the variance would be.

Comment: Just to clarify, Buffon's needle is another approach, not this approach, but it has similar properties.

Comment: This is the basic idea behind Monte Carlo integration. It's not a particularly good approach to doing integrals in one dimension but it's very useful in 3 or more dimensions as traditional techniques are horrifically slow by comparison.

Comment: You can run a one-line R code that will simulate this approach. You'll find that you need about 100,000 darts to get $\pi$ correct to about 2 decimal places. This method is quite inefficient, though cool.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. I just wrote a simple Python program with $10,000,000$ 'dart throws'. Here are the values of the estimate from five runs

$$3.141466, 3.142664, 3.1420584, 3.1422768, 3.1417728$$

So qualitatively, I'd say this is not a great method. By contrast, there are a number of series that can arrive at 4 significant figures of $\pi$ with far less calculation.

Comment: Can you share some of those series?

Comment: e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Rapidly_convergent_series

Comment: These are fascinating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a valid approach to compute $\pi$ provided the points are drawn randomly using the ***uniform distribution on the square***.